# Laravel 5.6 time ago in views

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

```
<?php

namespace project1\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use View;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
          $users  = DB::table('users')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(5)->get();
          return View::make('pages.dashboard.dashboard',['users' => $users]);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to echo the Time Ago in my View ( **pages.dashboard.dashboard** ) Something Like,

```
{{ $user->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
```

Expecting output like,

```
1 min ago
```

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Have you tried?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First, try an eloquent model.

`$users = App\User::orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(5)->get();`

in view

`@foreach($users as $user) {{$user->created_at->diffForHumans()}} @endforeach`

In Terms for your case

`$users = DB::table('users')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(5)->get();`

`@foreach($users as $user) 
    {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffForHumans()}} 
@endforeach`

Explanation

The **eloquent model automatically get casts to Carbon** instance and you can use an all methods

In the case of **DB query date (created_at) is not get parse so we have to parse manually**.

Comment: It's only working for 'hours ago'. not showing in seconds or minutes.

Answer (score 4):

maybe it would help you

A nice semi-hidden feature of timestamps in Eloquent is that they don't just return strings from the database - they actually return an instance of Carbon, a great extension of PHP's DateTime library. What this means is that a heap of functions (and I mean a heap) are available right on your model's timestamps. It's worth having a read through the GitHub README to see what is available, but one of the coolest methods is diffForHumans(), a handy little function providing the long sought-after "time ago" format we often need.

```
$user = User::first();
echo $user->created_at->diffForHumans(); // 2 days ago

$user->touch();
echo $user->created_at->diffForHumans(); // a second ago
```

Or

If created_date is an instance of Carbon\Carbon, you can do:

```
$row->created_date->diffForHumans()
```

If it isn't an instance of Carbon, you can do:

```
(new Carbon\Carbon($row->created_date))->diffForHumans()
```

Or you add the model property to the `$dates` casting list in the model, which will cast the property to a `Carbon` instance whenever you access it (like `$user->created_date`):

```
class User
{
    protected $dates = [
        'created_date',
    ];
}
```

The fields `created_at` and `updated_at` are added to this casting list automatically if `$timestamps` of a model is set to `true`. Also `deleted_at` will be added if soft deletes are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.5> just write

{{ $date->created_at->diffForHumans() }}

Returns whatever time ago

Answer (score 0):

just write `->diffForHumans();` after your time.
like `$record->created_date->diffForHumans();`